# discord.js not sending message at specific time

Tags: discord.js

So I'm trying to make the bot send a message at a specific time (Hour, Minute, Second), at a specific channel. However, its really not doing what its programmed to do.

Right now, the time set is 15:25:00, however, its not sending the message on that time.

```
client.on("message", message => {
    var day = new Date();
    var hr = day.getHours();
    var min = day.getMinutes();
    var sec = day.getSeconds();

    if (hr == 15) {
    if (min == 25){
        if (sec == 0) {

            client.channels.get("704015571531857950").send("Test")

}
}
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always look at the parent function :) Your if conditions are in `client.on("message", message => { ... })`, meaning you only check the time when someone sends a message, only allowing the bot to send the message if someone sends a message exactly at 15:25:00. Also, to send a message to a specific channel, your method is outdated, here is the new solution:

```
client.channels.fetch("704015571531857950").then((channel) => {
    channel.send("Test");
});
```

Comment: Alright, so what ``client.on`` should I use in order to send a message at that specific time?

Comment: Neither, i would do it completely outside and in a `setInterval(function, 10000)` so the bot watches every 10 seconds and i would make the send time for him a bit wider because bots aren't always working every second, they have some silent times.

Answer (score 0):

setInterval every 10 seconds is bad for prefromance, I would suggest doing some math and using setTimeout, although setTimeout might be a bit off, don't think it would be too much.

like vrecusko said your method is outdated, but using fetch isn't the only/best option.

```js
client.channels.cache.get("704015571531857950").then(channel => {
   channel.send("Message");
});
```

Can you explain what you are doing further? Is there a command where you set the time to send a message? Or is this like a message you want the bot to send every day at the same time?

Comment: I actually already figured it out with vrecusko20's solution. Even though the outdated method apparently works. I'm just trying to make it periodically send a message at a specific time.